# why is my Jenkinsfile throwing up workflowscript errors?

Tags: validation, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm still very new on jenkins. I am trying to build a docker image, test it and push to registry.

the test stage involves ensuring http endpoint is able to return status code 200
I have issues with my Jenkinsfile codes throwing up errors. I installed jenkins pipeline linter to help but it brings new errors as soon as I clear one.
I appreciate some help with my jenkinsfile codes to correct my mistakes. Thankyou.

please see codes below:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    options {
        buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '5'))
    }
    environment {
        DOCKERHUB_CREDENTIALS = credentials('dockerhub')
    }

    stages {
        stage('Build image') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh 'docker build -t (stlng/freeze-$env.BRANCH_NAME:$env.BUILD_NUMBER) .'
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Test image') {
            agent
            stages {
                steps {
                stage('Launch app') {
                    steps {
                        sh 'docker compose -f freeze.yml up -d'
                    }
                }

                stage('testing endpoint') {
                    steps {
                        httpRequest url:'http://localhost:8000',
                        validResponseCodes:'200'
                    }
                }

                stage('shutting down app') {
                    steps {
                        sh 'docker compose -f freeze.yml down'
                    }
                }
                }
            }
        }
        stage('dockerHub login') {
            steps {
                sh 'echo $DOCKERHUB_CREDENTIALS_PSW | docker login -u $DOCKERHUB_CREDENTIALS_USR --password-stdin'
            }
        }

        stage('Push image to registry') {
            steps {
                sh 'docker push (stlng/freeze-$env.BRANCH_NAME:$env.BUILD_NUMBER)'
            }
        }

        stage('dockerhub logout') {
            steps {
                sh 'docker logout'
            }
        }

 /*** workspace clean up*/
        post {
            always  {
                sh 'docker system prune'
                cleanWs()
            }
        }
        }
    }
```

below are some of the last errors. new ones come up once I manage to clear a set.

```
Errors encountered validating Jenkinsfile:
WorkflowScript: 19: Not a valid stage section definition: "agent". Some extra configuration is required. @ line 19, column 9.
           stage('Test image') {
           ^

WorkflowScript: 22: Expected a stage @ line 22, column 17.
                   steps {
                   ^

WorkflowScript: 63: Expected a stage @ line 63, column 9.
           post {
           ^

WorkflowScript: 21: No stages specified @ line 21, column 13.
               stages {
               ^
```

My original Jenkinsfile was without the Test stage and cleanup stage (please see below), and it worked well. The errors started as I tried to introduce the 2 stages.

```
  pipeline {
  agent any
  options {
    buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '5'))
  }
  environment {
    DOCKERHUB_CREDENTIALS = credentials('dockerhub')
  }
  stages {
    stage('Build image for app') {
      steps {
        sh 'docker build -t stlng/freeze-master:0.0.1 .'
      }
    }
    stage('Login to docker hub') {
      steps {
        sh 'echo $DOCKERHUB_CREDENTIALS_PSW | docker login -u $DOCKERHUB_CREDENTIALS_USR --password-stdin'
      }
    }
    stage('Push docker image to docker hub registry') {
      steps {
        sh 'docker push stlng/freeze-master:0.0.1'
      }
    }
  }
  post {
    always {
      sh 'docker logout'
    }
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have steps that nest a stage, which isn't valid. You can have nested stages within stages if you want. However, steps cannot encompass a stage.

```
stage('Test image') {
    agent
        stages {
            steps { // <----This is the problem
                stage('Launch app') {
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrew Nolan, but I took out the line but still got more errors on other lines